# Show Image from Byte[] in monotouch

Tags: iphone, image, stream, uiimage, xamarin.ios

I am working in Monotouch framework, in which i have to show image, what i have is byte[].

so i used

```
    Public static Public static UIImage GetImagefromByteArray (byte[] byteArrayIn){
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream ())
        {
            byte[] streamBytes = new byte [byteArrayIn.Length];
            memStream.Read( streamBytes, 0, byteArrayIn.Length);
            NSData data = NSData.FromArray( streamBytes );
            return UIImage.LoadFromData( data );
        }              
    }
```

but it always returns null, i searched for it so came to know that it is a bug in monotouch. 
[bug reported link](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.mono.bugs/29509), so what else function may i use to show image .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You are reading from an empty MemoryStream. UIImage.LoadFromData works fine in MonoTouch 4.0 (and since 3.2.* from what I can remember). Try the following method, you don't need a MemoryStream if you already have the byte buffer of the image, eg. from a FileStream:

```
public static UIImage GetImagefromByteArray (byte[] imageBuffer)
{
    NSData imageData = NSData.FromArray(imageBuffer);
    return UIImage.LoadFromData(imageData);
}
```

Comment: **NSData imageData** should be wrapped in a using statement.